# Using LiveData & Observer with Activity & Service

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, observers, android-viewmodel

I am building an app which has to perform some background work for which I am using a service. I have to start the background loading of the service in my Splash Screen and then in Activity A, I have to just get the progress once and then show it to the user. But when the user opens the Activity B then I have to get a live update of the data i.e whenever the data is updated from the Service I have to get the update to my Activity B only if it is visible to the user.

How can I achieve that using Live Data and Observer which is lifecycle aware?

Comment: save progress percentage is in room and call livedata observer wherever you required

Comment: @skyshine Thanks for the answer. Can you please post an answer with basic code so that I can accept it.